# xcode error Unable to find a team with the given Team ID to which you belong.

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate

I am getting the following error in Xcode,

`Unable to find a team with the given Team ID 'E4K95C67LT' to which you belong.  Please contact Apple Developer Program Support.
https://developer.apple.com/support`

This is after I was kicked off a team and started my own dev account. Do I need to reinstall Xcode or something?

In Xcode it shows my new Team, and when I click on the team it took me to a place where I created signing identities, but when I go to build app it says no signing identity found and asks me if I want Xcode to try and fix issue, I click fix Issue and this error pops up.

Any ideas? I really don't see much help on the apple dev support website, everything seems to be set up correctly on their side. Is there anyway to renew the Team ID?

Comment: Check your project's settings. You probably have the old team associated with it. Incidentally, if you've been kicked off a project's team, do you *really* think you should continue working on it?

Comment: I stopped working on their project a while ago and started another project, didn't realize I was using the old team until they kicked me off...

Comment: In my case I had opened a sample project that I downloaded from Apple (MetalBasic3D), and it turned out to have a team id saved in it. Changing that to my team fixed the problem, and the old team cruft disappeared.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I just needed to restart Xcode after changing the teams.

Comment: Sadly, this is often the correct answer to Xcode problems.

Answer (score 19):

Just go to your Project-Targets-General-Identity-Team.

Change your team and ready!