# Xcode development team not showing (Unable to find a team with the given Team ID 'xxxxxx' to which you belong. )

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am developing an IOS app and I have successfully released it to app store before using my own apple id (individual team). Today I closed my xcode and reopened it, then I wanted to add my apple id ( already enrolled in apple developer program ) to xcode, but there is no development team for this apple id according to xcode.

**(Edit), I am using Automatically Manage Signing from Xcode**

I tried to remove my apple id, then add it again, or restart my computer, restart xcode. Nothing works! I see nothing under the "teams". I went to https://developer.apple.com and I still see my individual team under my apple id, but it is just not showing on Xcode!

[This is the screen in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJVBS.png)

[This shows that my account still has a developer team on the developers portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Is8.png)

After digging around a lot, I realize I cannot access the "Certificates, Profiles" option in my developers portal, and I got an error message here which makes me believe something happened to my individual development team. This is ridiculous! My team ID shows on my developer portal but now they say my team has disappeared?

[Screen showing error that my developer team cannot be found. Same team ID in my developer portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlAPS.jpg)

I notice this is similar to thread: [xcode error Unable to find a team with the given Team ID to which you belong.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992418/xcode-error-unable-to-find-a-team-with-the-given-team-id-to-which-you-belong)

However the difference is I faced this problem on developers portal not Xcode, and restarting Xcode is useless, I am suspecting something happened to my team settings on the developers portal and that is why Xcode cannot find my team. Anyone faced similar problems?

Comment: Hi, you can try to remove all "Signing" information from your build settings tab

Comment: @JimmyJames I tried that, it is not working

Comment: take a look at this link and solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674208/development-team-not-showing-in-xcode

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue , problem resolve by selecting this tick when giving access to me by owner.

[image]

Comment: Why is that grayed out?

Comment: If i'ts an individual developer account , it's grayed out.